# Marcar texto com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, android

Gostaria de criar uma marcação de texto em uma página HTML feita pelo JavaScript. Fiz um método que consigo obter os pontos inicial e final de uma seleção feita pelo usuário e salvá-las no Android, mas não faço ideia de como criar a marcação do texto em HTML após a página ser carregada novamente. Sei que tenho que passar os parâmetros do ponto inicial e final do texto, mas não acerto na sintaxe.

Eu ainda não compreendi o uso do addRange mostrado neste exemplo
http://help.dottoro.com/ljcpcpnt.php

Neste tutorial é explicado como criar a marcação de texto selecionado pelo usuário trocando seu estilo:
http://tech.pro/tutorial/1075/javascript-highlighting-selected-text

Comment: convém mostrar que código tens feito para nós ajudar-mos e apontar-mos onde está certo ou errado... usa o jsfiddle.net

Comment: Olá amigo, eu não tenho um código para isso, pois não tenho muito conhecimento em javascript.